# Время выполнения методов классов

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно каким-то образом, выводить время выполнения методов заданного класса ?

Т.е. хотелось бы использовать подобным образом:

getTimeMethots("className");

И если у этого класса вызываются какие-то методы, то должно выводиться время их выполнения.

Возможно ли это реализовать из вне (т.е. не изменяю функционал самого класса и их метода) ? Через reflection или еще как-то ?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ получить метку времени до и после вызова, а потом найти разность.

Для большей универсальности можно попробовать сделать это через рефлексию, но смысла этим заниматься, ИМХО, особо нет, т.к. есть готовые профилировщики (например, [XHProf](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+php+%D1%81+xhprof))

Answer (score 1):

Я наверное переборщу, но мы используем [Pinba](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinba)

в своем проекте если хватит терпения, то это лучший сервис мониторинга.

[Хороший пример настройки](https://prudnitskiy.pro/2015/11/26/pinba/)

Если он не подходит, то на хабре много информации по настройки